# Why isn't the image displaying in my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, image

i added the image in the imageshown folder and still im unable to view the image on the webpage.
help me my dear friends i added conditions to display image according to the car shown.but it doesnt work even after trying other ways to which i found here.

```js
/* this is an event */
//alert('Im Annoying');
var username = prompt("Enter Your Name");
var car = ["Bmw", "Mercedes", "Koenigsegg"];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * car.length);
var randcar = car[randomNumber]
if (username === "Nilesh") {
  document.write("<h1>Hello " + username + " you won a " + randcar + "!</h1>");
  if (randcar === "Bmw") {
    var imageshown = "Koenigsegg.jpg"
  } else if (randcar === "Mercedes") {
    var imageshown = "Koenigsegg.jpg"
  } else {
    var imageshown = "Koenigsegg.jpg"
  }
} else if (username === "Chris") {
  document.write("<h2>Hey " + username + " You Won A " + randcar + "!</h2>");
  if (randcar === "Bmw") {
    var imageshown = "Koenigsegg.jpg"
  } else if (randcar === "Mercedes") {
    var imageshown = "Koenigsegg.jpg"
  } else {
    var imageshown = "Koenigsegg.jpg"
  }
} else {
  document.write("<h3>" + username + " Go Cry On Your Mom's Lap !</h3>");
  var imageshown = "Koenigsegg.jpg"
}
document.getElementById('img').src = imageshown;
```

```css
/* Basic CSS comment */

body {
  background: beige;
  color: white;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 30px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #333;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #a61250;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #7d1db5;
}
```

```html
<img id='img' src=imageshown>
```

i wanted to see an image but the image just doesnt show how to fix this someone help!!

Comment: Because your `document.write` erases all HTML and than there is no `#img` in your DOM.

Comment: The path for the image doesn't appear to be recognised

For example is the image in a folder called images? - in this case it would be `./images/Koenigsegg.jpg`

Comment: Try remove this ```src=imageshown``` in ```<img id = 'img' src=imageshown>```.

Comment: Your code is working fine. It's probably because there is no image in that folder. You have to show us the folder contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to show the image is correct. However, your sequence is wrong as you know code run from top to bottom.

Your current code loads the the javascript code first then it loads the element of the `<img>`

To fix this, move`<script>` to the bottom of your body. :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Week 1 of learning java script.</title>
    <style>
      /* Basic CSS comment */
        body {
          background: beige;
          color: white;
          width: 960px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          font-size: 30px;
        }

        h1 {
          font-size: 80px;
          color: #333;
        }

        h2 {
          font-size: 80px;
          color: #a61250;
        }

        h3 {
          font-size: 80px;
          color: #7d1db5;
        }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <img id='imgss' src="" >
     <script>
      /* this is an event */
      //alert('Im Annoying');
      var username = prompt("Enter Your Name");
      var car = ["Bmw", "Mercedes", "Koenigsegg"];
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * car.length);
      var randcar = car[randomNumber]
      if (username === "Nilesh") {
          document.write("<h1>Hello " + username + " you won a " + randcar + "!</h1>");
          if (randcar === "Bmw") {
              var imageshown = "oldlogo.jpg"
          }
          else if (randcar === "Mercedes") {
              var imageshown = "oldlogo.jpg"
          }
          else {
              var imageshown = "oldlogo.jpg"
          }
      }
      else if (username === "Chris") {
          document.write("<h2>Hey " + username + " You Won A " + randcar + "!</h2>");
          if (randcar === "Bmw") {
              var imageshown = "oldlogo.jpg"
          }
          else if (randcar === "Mercedes") {
              var imageshown = "oldlogo.jpg"
          }
          else {
              var imageshown = "oldlogo.jpg"
          }
      }
      else {
          document.write("<h3>" + username + " Go Cry On Your Mom's Lap !</h3>");
          var imageshown = "oldlogo.jpg"
      }
      document.getElementById('imgss').src = 'oldlogo.jpg';
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your file structure like? My code only works if the images and html file are in the same folder at the file path is not specified.

Comment: but what if i want to display the image after the text according to the question.

Comment: my images are in the same folder as the html file

Comment: but i want the images to be shown below the text

Comment: Why not do the same for your heading tags and edit the heading tag using javascript? This way you can use html to structure your elements and use javascript to load your data.